# STS v4.20 : Import spring kotlin project from repo but unable to run in STS

Tags: spring, git, kotlin, intellij-idea, sts

I have a spring kotlin gradle project that I created with intellij. All works fine in intellij but when I open with STS 4 the project is not recognized as a spring boot project and I am unable to run it. Any guidance will help.

1. kotlin plugin installed from marketplace
2. In 'Run Configuration' I get "No project selected" when adding to Spring Boot App
3. I don't see  see "[boot]" next to the project name